# how to find whether we are at the End of MS WORD page in xml?

Tags: xml, ms-word, obiee

I need to find whether we are at the bottom of the page or not. I am creating a template in WORD using BI Publisher, how can I find that We have hit the end of page, I actually have to put a check where if its the end of page and a certain condition is true then Stop showing records. Is there any tag used in xml through which I can find the end of the MS word page